# Views AJAX reset Hook

Tags: 7, views, theming, hooks

I found a solution that replaces the default reset functionality by an AJAX , It's working fine in my Bootstrap Theme , but I have one problem ! when I click the reset button the dropdown select list don't back to the Field Label but it's look empty ??!!
what can i change to make it work ?

I'm using Drupal 7

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_alter().
*/

function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

// Get the submission button ID
$submit_btn_id = $form['submit']['#id'];

$form['reset']['#attributes'] = array('onclick' => "javascript:jQuery(this.form).clearForm();jQuery(this.form).find('#$submit_btn_id').trigger('click');return false;");

}
```

Comment: Something about this approach doesn't feel right. Why not use an `#ajax` callback(s) to clear and rebuild the form?